# Regular users logs in as ADMIN if Admin logged in recently

Tags: wp-admin

Just found a crazy vulnerability and have no idea how to fix it.

Here is a situation:

1. Admin logs in to a website.
2. Regular user logs in using their credentials within the next few minutes
3. Instead of logging in to their profile, they get access to admin resources. Their username is reflected as admin and they have access to all the features.

Why is this happening and how to stop it?

That's not the first time it happens and I am really concerned about it. I am using optimizepress plugin for creating custom login page. Don't know if it may be related to the problem

Comment: Sounds like you implemented full page caching but didn't restrict it to logged out users only. Standard WP core doesn't have this behaviour. If Optimizepress is to blame you should raise it as a bug with them, otherwise you'll need to look at the caching provider, be that a CDN, your host, or a plugin

Comment: does optimizepress have a default permissions for logged in users who use the custom login pages? Allot of those types of plugins have a default role to assign to users who successfully login.

Comment: @TomJNowell I do use wp-rocket for caching, but the logged in users cache is disabled there by default. Do you have any idea about the steps to troubleshoot it?

Comment: @Elgoots it doesn't seem to be the case as it happens very rarely. And the problem is that even though they are logging in with their credentials, they end up being logged in with MINE

Comment: I cannot help but think Tom is on to something with caching sessions or cookies somewhere, even though it is hard to believe. have you tried disabling all caching , code compression/minify if any and trying to see if it does it?